# Is it possible to disable a minor mode (e.g. flyspell) on a per-file basis?

Tags: emacs

One can enable a minor mode by specifying something like `mode:flyspell` in [file local variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables).  In my case, I want flyspell to be on by default for my org buffers (which I can set up via a hook), but there are a few files where I want to keep it turned off.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this (short of creating a new minor mode that would disable flyspell and enabling *that* using local variables)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defun my-no-flyspell-mode (&optional rest)
  (flyspell-mode -1))
```

You can disable flyspell mode using something like:

```
/* Local Variables: */
/* mode:org           */
/* mode:my-no-flyspell */
/* End:             */
```

And, this time, I've actually tested that it works ;)

Comment: ah, excellent! I should've thought of that.  Now go back to practicing swingouts :)

Comment: In fact, you did think of it, I got the idea directly from your question. Keep on practice -- there is no upper limit to excellence!

Comment: Yes, I did think of it but I didn't think it would be so simple :)  And yes, I'll keep on practicing -- my lindy hop is a little better than my elisp at the moment, but I'm trying to improve both.